# Running Multiple PHP SSH2 Script

Tags: php, macos, ssh, shutdown

I have a shop having about 10 Macs. 
Current I am able to shutdown/restart them remotely through PHP SSH2 function using this code

```
<?php
                include('Net/SSH2.php');

                $server = "hostname";
                $username = "user";
                $password = "pwd";
                $command = "sudo shutdown -r now";

                $ssh = new Net_SSH2($server);
                if (!$ssh->login($username, $password)) {
                    exit('Login Failed');
                }

                echo $ssh->exec($command);
                echo "Sucessfully Restarted blah blah blah";
            ?>
```

But in order to shutdown/restart 10 of the terminals, I have to run 10 different script to achieve that. Is there any methods where I can connect to multiple server and run the same command?

Comment: You have a list of host names and credentials? You could store these in an array and loop through them issuing the command to each SSH host.

Comment: Is there any site to visit to help me with the array and loop thingy? Just only learned php for the above function. Not really sure what should I look for! Thanks :)

Comment: Bare with me. What version on PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP 7.0.0 :) Using one of my MAMP on one of my MAC :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the hostnames and credentials in a multi-dimensional [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). This will allow you to iterate through each item using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and execute the required command on each host. Here's an example of what you'd need to do:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$hosts = array(
    array(
        'hostname' => 'hostname1',
        'username' => 'user1',
        'password' => 'pwd1'
    ),
    array(
        'hostname' => 'hostname2',
        'username' => 'user2',
        'password' => 'pwd2'
    )
);

$command = "sudo shutdown -r now";

foreach ($hosts as $host) {
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($host['hostname']);

    if (!$ssh->login($host['username'], $host['password'])) {
        echo "Login Failed for host '{$host['hostname']}'\n";

        continue;
    }

    echo $ssh->exec($command);
    echo "Sucessfully Restarted {$host['hostname']}\n";
}
```

Hope this helps.

*On security: It's recommended you use SSH keys rather than usernames and passwords. Also, make sure you keep the macs on a network that is not open, for example, to customers, you should use a private network.*

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it tomorrow when I'm back in shop :)
Erm I tried using SSH keys, I only able to get one terminal working.
After generating the keygen, i did this 
`"cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@123.45.56.78 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`
I can only successfully, transfer the public to one host, when I tried to do it on another host, it kept saying id_rsa.pub not found. :( Tried it with two server but both failed. Is there anyway I can put it my thumbdrive and transfer it manually? :)

Comment: Your solutions for the array is working! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Is it possible for each host to output the fail or success to a variable?

so e.g. later down in the local site
I can call `$host1status, $host2status, $host3status` etc, and it will return the value whether it successfully  login or not. Right now it is all echo-ed back in one chunk. Thank you in advance!
@Yottatron

Comment: Sry, my reputation is below 15, can't give you an up :(

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error and trying to understand the code. I have solved it with a little modification to your code. Added one more "name" in each array. Then afterwards, remove echo, and replace it with a variable. So whenever I want to get the status, I can just call the value.

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$hosts = array(
    array(
        'hostname' => 'hostname1',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pwd',
        'name' => '1sthost'  
    ),
    array(
        'hostname' => 'hostname2',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pwd',
        'name' => '2ndhost'  
    )
);

$command = "shutdown -r now";

foreach ($hosts as $host) {
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($host['hostname']);

    if (!$ssh->login($host['username'], $host['password'])) {
        $$host['name'] = "{$host['hostname']}\n failed";

        continue;
    }

    echo $ssh->exec($command);
    $$host['name'] = "{$host['hostname']}\n success";

}

?>


<?php echo $1sthost; ?>
<?php echo $2ndhost; ?>
```